# Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.event.destroy] [URI: admin/evenment/event/{id}]

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes, submit, laravel-blade

Hey guys i have an error when i submit the delete it says that i'm not sending the id to the route i think,
that's the code to send the id to the route (and sorry for my english),

```
<form id="del_type" action="{{ route('admin.event.destroy',$event->id)}}" method="post">
                                {!! method_field('delete') !!}
                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" id="del_id">Supprimer</button>
```

it's wierd cause when i submit it's deleting the element from the database but with this error and in the URI i can see the id
take a look at the routes (All route names are prefixed with 'admin.')

```
Route::delete('evenment/event/{id}','EventController@destroy')->name('event.destroy');
```

Comment: your route name is `event.destroy` not `admin.event.destroy`

Comment: All route names are prefixed with 'admin.'

Comment: What's the value of `$event->id`? Are you sure it's not `null`?

Comment: no it's not null .. i don't know where's the problem

Comment: What you mean with “all the route starti with admin.”?

Comment: change method with this ` @method('DELETE')`

Answer (score 0):

change route to

```
admin.event.destroy
```

Comment: All route names are prefixed with 'admin.'

Comment: change method filed with {{ method_filed('DELETE') }}

Comment: which laravel version you use?

Comment: try to change action to action="{{ route('admin.event.destroy',['id']=>$event->id)}}"

Comment: i'm using laravel 5.8 , and i got a syntax error when i added this code syntax error, unexpected '=>'

Comment: ok use csrf and delete method like this @csrf and @method('DELETE')

Comment: its the same error again but why ? i'm passing the id in the url (http://stage.test/admin/evenment/event/2)

Answer (score 0):

Change `action` to this and try

```
 {{ route('admin.event.destroy', ['id' => $event->id])}}
```

Comment: same problem :/ This is starting to get weird

Comment: the delete works fin so the id is passing from the view to the route and to the controller . i dont understand why there is an issue in this